# communicate() does not catch suprocess stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

```
import subprocess    
def ExecuteAndGetValue(cmd, v):
        PrintCmd(cmd, v)
        sub = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  
        result = sub.communicate()
        sub.wait()
        return result

import subprocess    
def ExecuteAndGetValue2(cmd, v):
    PrintCmd(cmd, v)
    sub = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)  
    result = sub.communicate()[0]
    return result


[aa, err] = Util.ExecuteAndGetValue(cmd, args.v)  # run half an hour, the output size is about 15MB
[bb, err] = Util.ExecuteAndGetValue(cmd, args.v)  # run half an hour, the output size is about 15MB
print aa  // aa is empty
print bb // bb is empty
```

`cmd` prints/outputs:  stderr using `print >> sys.stderr` and stdout using `print`

```
result = []
for i in range(n):
    print >> sys.stderr, "T_index: " + str(T_index)
    bb = func(i)
    result.append(bb)
print '\n'.join(result)
```

cmd has a loop in which print `stderr` info. At the end, it prints all output to `result`

(1) if `cmd` print smaller size string, it works fine. `aa` and `bb` shows correct results.

(2) if `cmd` print a large size such as 10 Mb, `aa` and `bb` are empty.

(3) based on the above tests, it looks to me that sub.communicate()[0] read stdout from Popen in real time? if it is a large stdout, it cannot read it? Could someone explain it a little more ?

In addition, I would like to see stderr or error message in screen in real time. If I use the following, it does not show stderr in real time:

```
import subprocess    
def ExecuteAndGetValue(cmd, v):
        PrintCmd(cmd, v)
        sub = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)  
        result = sub.communicate()
        print result[1]
        return result
```

How can I fix this problem? it might be related to buffer size? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use stderr parameter in your Popen call.

```
sub = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
return sub.communicate()
```

You need not use sub.wait() - communicate() waits for the command execution to be completed and returns the output/error message.

Comment: I want to print the err info in console in realtime. So, if I add stderr = subprocess.PIPE. It does not print the infomation. How can I print the error information realtime?

Comment: subprocess.communicate() returns both output and error messages. If you cannot print the error message, there may be no errors.

And to answer your other question on buffer size, communicate should be able to flush the info in buffer and it shouldn't cause any deadlock. Check [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-objects) for more information.

Comment: Thanks, I add some code to show how `cmd` runs in background, it uses a loop and each loop prints stderr, however, if I use `ubprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)` it does not print the results in each loop when `cmd` is running.